# How can I adjust the borders when using Powertoys fancy zones?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powertoys

I am trying out the fancy zones in Powertoys, but there are borders to separate out each tab. How can I disable those borders so adjacent tabs stick to each other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Open PowerToys Settings -> Fancy Zones
- Launch FancyToys Editor
- Click the edit button
- Set Space around the zones to 0. Click Save.

[image: Edit Grid Window]